# Using delegate to pass selectedIndex data between two TabbarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have two `UITabbarControleller` with exactly the same items in a split view. The first one is connected as the `primary view` and the second one is connected as the `Secondary view`. I want when an index is selected in the first `Tabbar`, it would be deactivated in the second `Tabbar` and vice versa. 
First I want to pass data with closure, but apparently I couldn't use the segue between `splitViewController` and another controllers. So I decided to use Delegate to pass the `selectedIndex` of the `Tabbar`

Here is the protocol that I use

```
protocol primaryIndexDelagate {
func primaryDidSelectIndex(index: Int)
}
```

and here is the controller of the `primary Tabbar` that should pass the data to the `secondary TabBar`.

```
class PrimaryTabbar: UITabBarController {


 var didSelectIndexDelegate: primaryIndexDelagate?



override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item == self.tabBar.items?[0]{
        didSelectIndexDelegate?.primaryDidSelectIndex(index: 0)
    } else if item == self.tabBar.items?[1]{
        didSelectIndexDelegate?.primaryDidSelectIndex(index: 1)
    } else if item == self.tabBar.items?[2]{
        didSelectIndexDelegate?.primaryDidSelectIndex(index: 2)
    } else if item == self.tabBar.items?[3]{
        didSelectIndexDelegate?.primaryDidSelectIndex(index: 3)
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
 } 
}
```

And here is the secondary controller

```
class SecondaryTabbar: UITabBarController, primaryIndexDelagate {


func primaryDidSelectIndex(index: Int) {
    self.tabBar.items?[index].isEnabled = false

}

func delegateFromPrimay(){
    let primary = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "primaryTabBar") as! PrimaryTabbar
    primary.didSelectIndexDelegate = self

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegateFromPrimay()        
}    
}
```

The problem is, when i tap on any index, the app will be crashed with this error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

It found the delegate `nil`

[Screenshot from the line of the code that error is occurred on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ISxL.png)

Do you have any idea how to fix it, or do you know a better way to do that?
many thanks

Comment: you sure its not `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "primaryTabBar") as! PrimaryTabbar` that fails?

Comment: no, i set a breakpoint, it will crash when it want to add index to the delegate. See the screenshot

Comment: I think the problem is, when you set the index, you are setting it to newly created Primary tab bar in you delegateFromPrimay method. you should access the PrimaryTabbar that is already instantiated and set the delegate to that one

Comment: You should explicitly set the didSelectIndexDelegate.

Comment: can you show your view hierarchy?